# Make conditional Eloquent relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Laravel 5.7. I have an Eloquent model `Theme`, with two fields, `id` and `name`.

Another model, `Filter`, has three fields: `id`, `name`, `theme_id`.

**Filter:**

```php
class Filter extends Model
{
    public function theme()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Theme');
    }
}
```

I can attach these filters to an arbitrary number of other models, e.g. the model `Foo` has two fields, `id` and `name`. I attach the filter to it using a `Filterables` table:

**Filterables:**

```
id | filter_id | filterable_id | filterable_type
------------------------------------------------
1  |  1        |  3            |  App\Foo
```

The above example shows that the `Filter` of `id` 1 is attached to the `Foo` of `id` 3.

Now to get all the filters of `Foo`, I have this relationship in my `Foo` model:

**Foo:**

```php
class Foo extends Model
{
    public function filters()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Filter', 'filterable');
    }
}
```

This all works fine. But now I want to get the `Foo` model, and only the filters where the filter's `theme_id` is (for example) `1`.

How can I add this condition to the `filters` relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a where clause directly to your relationship

```
class Foo extends Model
{
    public function filters()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany('App\Filter', 'filterable')->where('theme_id', 1);
    }
}
```